# How to create wireless link on same LAN?

Tags: networking, wifi, wireless-bridge

We have a cluster of workstations and printers in the middle of a space and I would like to avoid running a physical Ethernet cable to them. Several of the printers do not have WiFi capabilities. The distance between our main access point and this "cluster" is approximately 40'.

I would like to create a wireless link from our main WiFi AP (Ruckus) to this cluster of machines and printers. Conceptually, I see this as an AP connected to a switch, then all of the machines and printers connected to the switch. The wireless link would essentially behave exactly like a long wire between our main switch and this new switch located in the cluster.

Sometimes a diagram can help :)

[image]

Clearly I'm not experienced with networking so I'm very likely missing an obvious solution. I've read about bridges but I see phrases like "Link two separate networks" but I'm not confident in the exact meaning. Physically separate? If that is the case, it's what I'm after. Or separate like different DHCP, sub-net, etc.?

We're a tiny little business with an even tinier budget. Any SOHO sized solution would be acceptable.

Comment: what is the distance between main office and the cluster ?

Comment: 40 feet. I've updated my question with this detail.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of setup , i will use a PowerLine  Adapter  to extend you local network .

Maximun bandwith you can have with powerline adapter are faster than Wifi

The solution need to purchase :

- 2 PowerLine Adapter
- 1 switch
- 1 regular SOHO access   point , configured in  repeater mode

  ```
                / RUCKUS               
  rj 45 cable   |                      
                \ POWER LINE ADAPTER A \
                                       |            
                                       | your power network 
                                       |            
                / POWER LINE ADAPTER B /
                |
                \ SWITCH A          
                  | | |  \____  ACCESS POINT      
                  | | \________ PRINTER A      
                  | \__________ PRINTER B
                  \____________ ....
  ```

More information about Power-Line
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-line_communication

=========================

If you a wifi only solution , i saw this article that explain  the requirement .

https://learntomato.flashrouters.com/setup-wireless-repeater-wds-bridge-tomato/

=========

You must use WDS to do your bridging

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_distribution_system

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion and make use it, but I am still interested in a wifi based solution. Hoping someone will offer a wifi based approach as well.